# Execute command for every file in the current dir

Tags: linux, bash

How can i execute a certain command for every file/folder in the current folder?

I've started with this as a base script, but this seems that its only working when using temporary files, and i dont really like the ideea. Is there any other way?

```
FOLDER=".";
DIRS=`ls -1 "$FOLDER">/tmp/DIRS`;

echo >"/tmp/DIRS1";
while read line ; do
    SIZE=`du "$FOLDER$line"`;
    echo $SIZE>>"/tmp/DIRS1";
done < "/tmp/DIRS";
```

---

For anyone interested, i wanted to make a list of folders, sorted by their size. Here is the final result

```
FOLDER="$1";
for f in $FOLDER/*; do 
  du -sb "$f";
done | sort -n | sed "s#^[0-9]*##" | sed "s#^[^\./]*##" | xargs -L 1 du -sh | sed "s|$FOLDER||";
```

which leads to `du -sb $FOLDER/* | sort -n | sed "s#^[0-9]*##" | sed "s#^[^\./]*##" | xargs -L 1 du -sh | sed "s|$FOLDER||";`

Comment: They're directories. Not folders. ;)

Comment: See my answer [here](http://serverfault.com/q/62411/1293#62522) for a way to do this by calling `du` only once instead of *twice for each file*. You won't need a `for` loop. You can add `--max-depth=1` to the `du` in it if that's needed and you can add your `sed "s|$FOLDER||"`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Perhaps xargs, which reinvokes the command specified after it for each additional line of parameters received on stdin...

```
ls -1 $FOLDER | xargs du
```

But, in this case, why not...

```
du *
```

...?  Or...

```
for X in *; do
    du $X
done
```

(Personally, I use zsh, where you can modify the glob pattern to only find say regular files, or only directories, only symlinks etc - I'm pretty sure there's something similar in bash - can dig for details if you need that).

Am I missing part of your requirement?

Comment: The final script should display a list of files/folders sorted by size, ordered by size

Comment: Ah well, in that case `du * | sort -n -k1` alone should be enough. No?

Comment: Then you can pipe `du -b * | sort -n`, where -b specifies bytes: change it to -k for kilobytes etc but you need to use the same units to be able to compare and sort (see `man du` for options), and sort -n sorts on the numeric values of the first field (rather than an ASCII, textual comparison in which say "2" would be after "10").

Comment: `for f in $(ls -1 $FOLDER); do ` seems to do the trick. Now i need to figure out how to make the final list:)

Comment: @Quamis: `for f in $(ls -1 $FOLDER)` is less efficient as it invokes a subshell (another bash environment) then runs the ls program under that.  `for f in *` does what's called a glob expansion in the original shell.  Is there something about `*` that's not doing what you want?

Comment: @Qaumis: `for ... $(ls)` fails for filenames that include spaces. Use `for ... *`

Comment: @TonyDelroy, can you please look at this case?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482766/script-to-execute-command-to-all-files-in-folder?noredirect=1#comment77926070_45482766

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), and [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 12):

The `find` command will let you execute a command for each item it finds, too. Without further arguments it will find all files and folders in the current directory, like this:

```
$ find -exec du -h {} \;
```

The `{}` part is the "variable" where the match is placed, here as the argument to `du`. `\;` ends the command.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen an example of `find` that actually explained how the full command given actually works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is useless to parse output of `ls` to cycle over files. Bash can do it with wildcard expansion.

Storing the result of `du` in a variable to output it to a file is also a useless use of a variable.

What I suggest:

```
for i in ./tmp/DIRS/*
do
    du "$i" >> "/tmp/DIRS1"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with something like this?

```
function process() {
   echo "Processing $1"
}

for i in *
do
  process $i
done
```

You can put all the "work" you want done inside the function `process`. This will do it for your current directory.

Comment: Can you please look at this case?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482766/script-to-execute-command-to-all-files-in-folder?noredirect=1#comment77926070_45482766

Answer (score 0):

This works for every file in the current directory:

```
do
   /usr/local/mp3unicode/bin/mp3unicode -s cp1251 --id3v2-encoding unicode "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The invocation of action exec can be done by two ways:

- `find . -type d -exec du -ch {} \;`
- `find . -type d -exec du -ch {} +`

In the first command, the substitution {} occurs for each folder found. In the second one all the results of find are passed to exec at once, which matters, to obtain a final total.

https://www.eovao.com/en/a/bash%20find%20exec%20linux/2/bash-execute-action-on-find-(-exec)-for-each-file