# Script to execute command to all files in folder

Tags: php, nginx, exec

I am new to Freebsd/nginx, so similar QAs did not help me ;(
I was running a code:

```
$ext = pathinfo ($_FILES['rawexcel']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//get extension of file, run different converters depending on extension
if ($ext == 'xlsx' ) {   exec("/usr/local/bin/cnvt   /var/tmp/xls/result.xlsx  /var/tmp/result.csv "); } 
else 
if ($ext == 'xls' ) {   exec("/usr/local/bin/xls2csv -x /var/tmp/xls/result.xls* -b WINDOWS-1251 -c /var/tmp/result.csv -a UTF-8"); } 
/var/tmp/xls/
```

when my file names were constant(result.xls which then converted to result.csv) & I was processing files one by one; **cnvt** and **xls2csv** are converters. 
Now I have ajax upload and want to perform **exec** command for all files in a folder, keeping original file name. I tried to run same code with result.xls replaced with ***(star)** but it did not work.

what I have:

folder tmp/xls with excel files

what I want:

convert all excel files inna folder to .csv keeping their original names. 
Will appreciate any help.

**UPDATE: *the best way to execute a command for all files in directory to create/edit a script to make that, operating on all files in directory much easier in bash itself. Good luck.***

Comment: Where did you put the `*`? Presumably in the above code you meant `/var/tmp/xls/*.xls` (instead of `/var/tmp/xls/result.xls*`?)

Comment: @Andy yes, exec("/usr/local/bin/cnvt   /var/tmp/xls/*.xlsx  /var/tmp/");

didn't work

Comment: Please show where `$i` comes from.

Answer (score 1):

See how you extracted the extension...

> $ext = pathinfo ($_FILES['rawexcel']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

You can check the [pathinfo docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and you'll see how to get the filename without path or extension:

```
$filename = pathinfo($_FILES['rawexcel']['names'][$i], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Then you can use that...

```
if ($ext == 'xlsx' ) {
    exec("/usr/local/bin/cnvt   /var/tmp/xls/$filename.xlsx /var/tmp/$filename.csv ");
} else if ($ext == 'xls' ) {
    exec("/usr/local/bin/xls2csv -x /var/tmp/xls/$filename.xls -b WINDOWS-1251 -c /var/tmp/$filename.csv -a UTF-8");
}
```